# JavaScript Regex to avoid certain pattern in textbox

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I have a validation to be done. The below pattern(post Man/PostMan/post Man etc) should not be allowed in my text box.
    [P|p]*(OST|ost)*.*\s*[M|m][a|A][N|n]\s*(\d.)*

I have to add a few more validations to the same input such as:
Allow:

- Alphabets, Numbers and the special character "-"

And, must not allow:

- Any other special characters
- The above written pattern, anywhere I enter in the text box.

So the input

- I am waiting for postMan
- I am waiting for postMan ###
- Post Man has
  not come , **are invalid**

whereas,

- I am waiting for 123348-12
- I hope my question is understandable now, **are valid**

I have tried the following:

```
([a-z 0-9 A-Z \\-])\*((?!\b[P|p]\*(OST|ost)\*\\.*\s\*[M|m][a|A][N|n]\s\*(\d.)\*\b))\*([a-z 0-9 A-Z])
```

But It stops working once it finds a character that does not match. For example:

asdasd 666 # posttt -> it stops validating anything after the special character.

What should my regex pattern be?

Comment: What do you mean "it stops working?" Can you show us the code where you use the regex?

Comment: First of all, ignore case: `/p*(post)*\.*\s*man\s*(\d.)*/i`. Then it meant that I'm not allowed to write `I love that ost man!`?

Comment: This sounds like it may be overly complicated for a single regex.

Comment: Sounds like you need `^(?!.*[P|p]*(OST|ost)*\.*\s*[M|m][a|A][N|n]\s*(\d.)*)[a-zA-Z-]*$` that can be further fixed and enhanced.

Comment: Doesn't `*` mean "0 or more times"? Then your entire validation pattern reduces to `[Mm][Aa][Nn]` (I doubt that the `|` is doing what you think it's doing)

Answer (score 3):

## Description

```regex
^(?!.*?[Pp]*(OST|ost)*\.*\s*[Mm][Aa][Nn]\s*(\d.)*)[a-z0-9A-Z-]*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

<sub>** To see the image better, simply right click the image and select view in new window</sub>

This regular expression will do the following:

- not allow your first expression to match anywhere in your string
- will then only allow `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, and `-`

I would like to point out that if your string in only going to allow letters, numbers, and a hyphen then the test in your expression for a dot is not necessary. Also the multiple upper and lower case character sets can be removed by using the case insensitive flag.

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/oY0hK2/1

**Sample text**

```
aWoeed1#fde39393aii
aWoeed1fde39393AII
aWoeed1fde39393AIIpostman 3a
```

**Sample Matches**

```
aWoeed1fde39393AII
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [Pp]*                    any character of: 'P', 'p' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \1 (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      OST                      'OST'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      ost                      'ost'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of \1 (NOTE: because you are using a
                             quantifier on this capture, only the
                             LAST repetition of the captured pattern
                             will be stored in \1)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.*                      '.' (0 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [Mm]                     any character of: 'M', 'm'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [Aa]                     any character of: 'A', 'a'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [Nn]                     any character of: 'N', 'n'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \2 (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .                        any character except \n
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of \2 (NOTE: because you are using a
                             quantifier on this capture, only the
                             LAST repetition of the captured pattern
                             will be stored in \2)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-z0-9A-Z-]*            any character of: 'a' to 'z', '0' to '9',
                           'A' to 'Z', '-' (0 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```